# Is it possible to @extend a class defined in a .css file to a .scss file?

Tags: sass, extend

For example:

app.scss

```
@import url('orange.css');  
@import 'navel.scss';
```

orange.css

```
.orange {  
  color: orange;  
}
```

navel.scss

```
.navel {  
    @extend .orange;  
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In SASS if you add

```
@import "test.css";
```

or

```
@import url("test.css");
```

it is compiled to pure css `@import` directive. Because the file has a `.css` extension, the SASS preprocessor thinks that this is pure CSS and the code inside is not involved in the SASS language operations. In your example, if you try to extend `.orange` you will get:

```
The selector ".orange" was not found.
```

Shortly: the extending is possible only if you use SASS files.

Answer (score 1):

@extend is not possible by importing a CSS file. You have to

1. convert your css into an SCSS partial (or file)
2. @import this partial
3. @extend CSS classes

The downside to this is you would be left with duplication. Supposed this import is a 7000 line long CSS file (like bootstrap), then you are going to be in trouble